# WebHook GitHub -> Jenkins: 404 Not Found

Tags: github, jenkins

Estoy intentando automatizar las pruebas, lanzando eventos WebHook desde una cuenta profesional de GitHub.

#### Jenkins

La URL de mi proyecto en Jenkins es:

```
https://JENKINSSERVER/cib-markets-pro/job/cib-pymxplus/job/pruebas_github_1/
```

En la página de configuración del proyecto en Jenkins tengo marcada la casilla

> Build when a change is pushed to GitLab

Y URL que me indica Jenkins para su WebHook es:

```
https://JENKINSSERVER/cib-markets-pro/project/cib-pymxplus/pruebas_github_1
```

Además, tengo marcada la casillas `Push Events` en esa misma sección de la configuración.

#### GitHub

En GitHub, en la casilla `Payload URL`, tengo

```
https://JENKINSSERVER/cib-markets-pro/project/cib-pymxplus/pruebas_github_1
```

El `Content type` como `application/JSON` (aunque también he probado como `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`)

El `Secret` correctamente *copy/pasteado*.

En la sección `Which events would you like to trigger this webhook?`, tengo seleccionada la opción `Just the push event`.

Y, por supuesto, marcada la casilla de `Active`.

#### El problema

Ante cualquier `commit`, en la sección `Hooks` de GitHub me aparece:

> **Request / Headers**:
> Request URL: https://JENKINSSERVER/cib-markets-pro/project/cib-pymxplus/pruebas_github_1
> Request method: POST
> content-type: application/json
> ...
> **Response/Headers**:
> Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
> Content-Length: 496
> Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
> Server: Jetty(9.4.27.v20200227)
> Set-Cookie: 859889f4c83fc9741a1b03031aad4810=1cab934fb494596083dcc67d3dc7aa94; path=/; HttpOnly; Secure
> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
> **Response/Body**:
> ...
> <title>Error 404 Not Found</title>

Hasta donde soy capaz de ver, las URL coinciden. Sin embargo, el Jenkins insiste en responder un `Not Found` bastante desagradable :-(

¿ Que estoy haciendo mal ?

¿ Como lo soluciono ?

Comment: Se me ocurren 2 cosas. O bien jenkins no es público y github no es capaz de ver esa url. O bien "Build when a change is pushed to GitLab" Gitlab != github y por eso no funciona

Comment: Es un 404, y tengo respuesta. Osea, el server si está accesible. Sobre lo segundo ... puede, pero no he encontrado otra forma. Si activo los *scripts* de Git,el server `Jetty` sobre el que corre Jenkins me dice que faltan las *bread crumb*. Por lo visto es una opción de seguridad. Pero no tengo derechos de admin sobre Jenkins y no puedo tocar esas cosas :-(

Comment: Esto de administrar un proyecto pero no el propio server de Jenkins es un tostón :-(

Comment: Instale localmente jenkins para probar, y creo que encontré el problema. El plugin de jenkins de gitlab espera que gitlab le envie una petición con un header 'X-Gitlab-Event' con el tipo de hook ("push hook", "merge request hook", etc) pero como la petición la envia github, no envia ese header, sino 'X-GitHub-Event'. Use [estas instrucciones](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#getting-help) para ver el log.

Comment: Hay plugins específicos para github. Así que tendrás que pedir que te instalen el plugin correspondiente. https://plugins.jenkins.io/github/

Comment: Ya está resuelto, pero no he podido escribir la respuesta aún. Sin *plugins* ni nada. A ver si mañana ...